# Meteor server throws error with Accounts.addEmail() in a meteor method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need help figuring out why I am getting this error.

My method is defined in `app/server/methods.js`

```
Meteor.methods({

    myMethod: function(user) {

        Accounts.addEmail(user._id, "thisemail@email.com", true); // set verified to true
    }
});
```

My template has an event that is calling this method from the client.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({

    'click #this-button': function(e) {

        Meteor.call("myMethod", userObject, function(error, result) {

            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                // do something here
            } 
        });
     }
});
```

I keep getting an `Internal Server Error [500]` error back to the console.
When I check my server output it says: 
`Exception while invoking method 'myMethod' TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addEmail'`.

Can anyone help me figure out why it can't be found/used?

These are the list of packages I am using, and I thought this came packaged with the accounts-password package according to the Meteor Documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Accounts-addEmail).

`meteor-platform
iron:core
iron:router
less
zimme:iron-router-active
tomi:upload-server
tomi:upload-jquery
houston:admin
coffeescript
alanning:roles
edgee:slingshot
joshowens:accounts-entry
mystor:device-detection
underscore
email
accounts-password`

Comment: What version of meteor are you using and/or what does `grep -i "accounts-password" .meteor/versions` give you?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I have `accounts-password@1.1.1`

Comment: @DavidWeldon and my meteor version is `1.1.0.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the commit history correctly, it looks like [addEmail](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Accounts-addEmail) was added [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/dac019fda8a5e70b2dbec335b6605b04c0c034bc) as part of meteor 1.2.

The [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/) always reference the latest version, but your app is using version 1.1, which explains the missing function.

The solution may be as simple as running `meteor update`, however `accounts-entry` is ancient and it may be incompatible with meteor 1.2, as noted in [this issue](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry/issues/383).

If you can't or don't want to update, just leave a comment and I can suggest an alternative implementation.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I figured it was better in the long run to try and figure out how to update my project to the current meteor version. Got it working after that!! Cheers.